# Handle file upload progress on recyclerview item while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am working on a chat application. It has a chat activity similar to WhatsApp, This app has features like sending text messages and files(images/pdf/doc, etc.). We are using recyclerview for message list in chat activity. Recyclerview on chat activity has multiple view types like textview for text message and imageview for images and few other custom views for another file types like DOC and PDF. We have a custom view class for view type file. When a user sends a file (image, pdf, doc etc.) a view is created according to file type.

When a user sends a file to another user a new view is created and added to the list, we are also showing file uploading status like **uploading-in-progress**, **uploading-failed**, **uploading-success** on the chat item.

We are facing an issue here while a user sending multiple files to another user, and scroll the screen up and down, the views are re-cycled and the positions of views are changes, therefore while showing uploading status, we lost the older view on which the uploading starts. Now we have another view instance on that position.

Therefore, after scrolling the uploading progress is showing on another view. We just wants to show the uploading status on right place where it was before the scrolling.

We have tried out few ways like setting

`recyclerview.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(VIEW_TYPE_FILE, 0);`

It makes recylerview to not recycle the view file type ,but it makes the recylcerview scrolling very slow.

Kindly help with a solution. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could please provide some screenshots or diagrams of what you have and what you're trying to achieve/avoid.

The code for your adapters and viewholders would also be useful as it gives a idea of what you have at the moment and makes a starting point for people who want to post a solution.

Without those the advice you'll receive is likely to be vague and harder to implement.

Comment: You should change view type by data, don't try to change with only position. For ex.if(data.isMedia) return mediaViewType;
Please check this example.
https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b

Answer (score 0):

you can override two methods of Recycler View so that when you scroll item there position will not be changed. Once item position not changes you will know by using position variable where to put progress view.
Override these methods,

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The loading state should be attached to every object of the data that adapter has, not to the view, so when #onBindViewHolder is called you can get the object instance for the incoming position and you should show/hide the loading view there depending on the object loading state.

Don't forget to process this show/hide logic every time #onBindViewHolder is called to avoid wrong view states with the recycling view internal process.